# I cannot get my ip address in php

Tags: php, ip

I am trying to write a small script that prints ip of the client. I am trying to run it on my localhost, but I am not able to get the IP address. Instead I get something like ::1.

Here's the code:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>
```

Why this is not working as expected?

Comment: `::1` is (kind of) the IPv6 version of `127.0.0.1` (`localhost`). Your system must be using IPv6 when connecting to `localhost`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
::1
```

Is the loopback adress (127.0.0.1 in IPv4) in IPv6.

This is the expected behaviour. If you use Firefox, you can navigate to `about:config`, search for `disableIPv6` and set it to `true`. You'll then see 127.0.0.1.

So yes, it's working.

Comment: So it means it is working? Will I get correct IPs when I put it on a real server? Or should I convert it to ip4 (how?)?

Comment: @Vafello, yes, it is working.  This is not an IPv4 vs IPv6 issue at all.  It is simply the address that was used to connect to your web server. In your case, it was the loopback.  Don't worry.

Comment: Yes, it's working. You'll get an IPv4 if client connects with IPv4, IPv6 if client connects with IPv6.

Answer (score 2):

It is working correctly.  That is your IP addresses... the IPv6 version of it.  If you had connected over IPv4 it would have shown as 127.0.0.1.

These are loopback addresses.  They allow you to connect to your own computer without using an actual network interface. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_network_interface